# Code not working when executed through button in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that is not working or giving the expected result when it is run thourhg a button (By inserting button and assign the code's macro to the button).

However, when I press F5 it is working. Can you suggest where the error is?

```
Sub Weekend() 

Dim r, LastRow, RemainingDay As Double

LastRow = Range("M:O").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For r = 2 To LastRow
  RemainingDay = 0

    If Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 1 Or Weekday(Range("K" & r).Value, vbSunday) = 7 Then


         If InStr(1, Range("O" & r).Text, "Fail", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
         Select Case True
                Case InStr(Range("P" & r).Text, "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)") > 0, _
                InStr(Range("P" & r).Text, "Moved to SA (Failure)") > 0

             If Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                 Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
             Else
                 Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
             End If

       End Select
    End If
    End If
```

Comment: Please post the button code. Remember if you create button event code then change the name of the button, the code won't be called. If you create a breakpoint in the button code does it run?

Comment: I did not create any button code..I just clicked on "Insert" and selected the button and assigned control to it.

Comment: Do you have code something like this in your VBA editor: `Sub Button1_Click()`. Do you remember what the _Macro Name_ was when you inserted the button?

Comment: No, I do not have anything as `Sub Button1_Click()` in my editor. My macro is placed in a Sub with the name `Sub Weekend()`

Comment: Do you understand how your button is linked to `Sub Weekend`? There are many ways to link buttons to code. It's difficult for me to work out what you've done. If you right click your button and press Assign Macro, what is it assigned to?

Comment: I have linked it through "Assign Macro" option..and it shows the correct macro when I click on it again

Comment: OK so open your VBA editor click on the line that says `LastRow=`... and press F9 and you'll see a dot and red/orange line go though it. That is a breakpoint. Now click your button and your code should stop at the breakpoint. Press F8 to step through it and hover over variables to see their values.

Comment: @stackmark, remember I told you once to chose Sub names not to conflict with existing VBA functions, like `Weekend()`.. Maybe your issue is resolved if you do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that your ranges are not associating with the correct sheet when you are trying to execute the macro through the button.  Maybe your button is not on the same sheet as the code and this is causing the dissociation?  It would work when you press F5 because I'm assuming your code is in the sheet module that contains the range.  But when you move the triggering of the macro to a button, the range becomes ambiguous.  Whatever the cause, you should be able to fix it by qualifying all of your ranges with the sheet for that range.

So for instance if your ranges are on Sheet1, you would need to add the following lines to your code:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

And then you would need to change ALL instances of the use of Range the be qualified with the sheet, like the following.

Change this:

```
LastRow = Range("M:O").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

To this:

```
LastRow = ws.Range("M:O").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Do this everywhere you see the word Range.  Preface Range with ws and a dot.  This is so that Excel will know which sheet to look for the range on.  Because EVERY sheet in the workbook will have a range M1:O50 so you need to qualify the range with WHICH sheet you want the range to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

- Insert a new button
- Add the VBA code
- Choose the sheet to activate in your VBA code
- Call your current Sub Weekend